# What's the best way to capture all doubleclick events in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, double-click

I'm writing a Windows Forms app that uses a DataGridView control.  I have row select enabled on the control.  I would like to trap the DoubleClick event, but it doesn't seem to fire reliably - I often have to double-click on a row 2 or 3 times before the event is triggered.  Could anyone point me to a way to capture this more reliably?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [CellDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick.aspx) event.  The EventArgs have the Row and Column indexes.

Comment: This is the event that I'm using.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to track every double-click.  The action seems to be ignored more often when I'm double-clicking on a row that isn't already selected.

Comment: Hmph, that's odd, but double-clicking is always a little random anyway.  Have you tried RowDoubleClick?

Comment: There isn't a RowDoubleClick event, as far as I can tell.